# error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: r, api, url

rstudioでgetURL()を実行したところ、

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

というエラーが出てしましました。
gitのバージョンが古いのかと思い、gitを更新しましたが、解決できませんでした。
どうしたらいいでしょうか？
以下プログラム：

```
library(RCurl)
library(rjson)
api.key<-"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
url <- paste("https://opendata.resas-portal.go.jp/","api/v1-rc.1/prefectures",sep
= "")
x <- getURL(url,httpheader = paste('X-API-KEY:', api.key)) Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

以下のサイトを参考にしています。

[RESAS-APIをRで使ってみる - Qiita](http://qiita.com/aokikenichi/items/33cd6328b80fed117637)

Comment: gitのバージョンはgit version 2.22.0.windows.1でOSはWindows　10　Home で
R のバージョンは3.5.3でRstudioは1.2.1335です。（2019年4月にインストールしました。）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opendata.resas-portal.go.jp は TLS1.1, TLS1.2 のみのサポートとなっているので、
OSにインストールされている、あるいは RStudio とともにインストールされた OpenSSL のバージョンが古い(TLS1.0までしかサポートしていない)のではないでしょうか。

適切なアドバイスを得るためにはOSの種類やバージョン、RStudioのバージョンなどを書かれるとよいと思いますよ。